# Why isn't my cpanel or website using the new css file I just added?

Tags: css, cpanel

So this business wants me to edit their index.html page. I went into the cpanel, commented out the html that was no longer wanted and added some new html. (I thought I'd do this instead of deleting the file and adding a new one because of the small amount of changes I was making) I did however add a new css file to replace the other one. This file has the same name of course just a bunch of new css. Anyway I added the new stuff and it doesn't look like how it should. Here's the site as of now  https://gilbertmovingandstorage.com/  and this is what each section is supposed to look like https://i.stack.imgur.com/MaIQw.jpg. Using my devtools and going to source, I looked at the css file(css/template-style.css) and it still has the original file? Even though I deleted it and replaced it with my new version?

p.s the css posted in the snippet is the css thats on my cpanel and is what should be linked to the index. html file.

```css
html {
 scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

#first-block, #second-block, #third-block, #fourth-block {
text-align:center;
padding:3.5rem 0;
}
#carousel {
text-align:center;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
/*display: flex;
flex-direction: column;*/
/*background: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)), url(img/phone-slide.jpg);*/
}
#carousel .header-img {
width: 100%;
}
#carousel .phrase-wrap::after {
display: inline-block;
content: '';
position: absolute;
z-index: 1;
left: -990em;
right: -999em;
bottom: -999em;
top: -999em;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
}
.phrase-wrap {
position: absolute;
z-index: 1;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
color: white;
font-size: 3rem;
}
.phrase-wrap div, .phrase-wrap a{
display: inline-block; 
position: relative;
z-index: 2;
}
#quote-btn {
color: white;
background-color: #ce1616;
font-size: 1.7rem;
border-radius: 25px;
padding: 5px 17px 10px 17px;
cursor: pointer;
transition: all .3s  ease;
}
#quote-btn:hover {
 background-color: white;
 color: #245877;
 /*background-color: #1a435b;*/
}
#first-block {
background:#fff;
}
#second-block {
background:#e5e5e5;
}
#third-block {
background:#fff;
padding-bottom: 1.5rem;
}
.review-wrap {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-around;
 margin: 0 100px 0 70px;
}
#testimonials {
display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
padding: 0 10px;
}
#testimonials div{
flex: 1 20%;
margin: 30px;
}
#testimonials div span {
 margin-left: 8px;
}
#fourth-block {
background:#e5e5e5;
}
.hide {
 display: none;
}
.gallery-grid {
 padding: 15px 0;
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns: repeat(4, minmax(250px, 1fr));
 grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 250px);
 max-width: 80%;
 margin-right: auto;
 margin-left: auto;
 grid-gap: 15px;
}
.home-advisor {
 display: flex; 
 align-items: center; 
 position: relative; 
 top: 15px;
}
.scale {
 transform: scale(1.3);
}
.move-left {
 position: relative;
 left: -30px;
}
.img-wrap img {
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}

footer {
background:#fff;
padding:3.5rem 0;
}

.footer-quote-btn {
 background-color: #e5e5e5;
 display: inline-block;
 padding: 4px 12px 4px 12px;

}

@media screen and (max-width: 1600px) {
 .review-wrap div img:not(.scale) {
  transform: scale(0.9);
 }

 .scale {
  transform: scale(1.1);
 }
}

@media Screen and (max-width: 1527px) {
 #quote-btn {
  font-size: 1.3rem;
 }

 .move-left {
  left: -15px;
 }

 .review-wrap {
  margin: 0 50px 0 20px;
 }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1450px) {
 .gallery-grid {
  max-width: 90%;
 }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1250px) {
 .gallery-grid {
  max-width: 97%;
 }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1125px) {
 .hide {
  display: block;
 }

 .gallery-grid {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, minmax(250px, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: repeat(7, 250px);
 }

 .review-wrap {
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 50px;
 }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1080px) {
 .phrase-wrap {
  font-size: 2.7rem;
 }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 921px) {
 .home-advisor {
  top: 10px;
 }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 900px) {
#testimonials div{
 flex: 1 25%;
 margin: 30px;
}

.gallery-grid {
 grid-template-rows: repeat(7, 200px);
}

}

@media screen and (max-width: 805px) {
 .hide {
  display: none;
 }

 .gallery-grid {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, minmax(250px, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: repeat(10, 250px);
 }
}

#third-block h1 {
 margin-left: 30px;
 margin-right: 30px;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 771px) {
 .top-nav li a {
     padding: 1rem;
 }

 .phrase-wrap {
  font-size: 2.3rem;
 }

 #quote-btn {
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  padding: 5px 13px 10px 13px
 }

 .move-yelp {
  left: -5px;
 }
 
}

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .right {
  float:none;
  }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 650px) {
#testimonials div{
 flex: 1 100%;
}

.gallery-grid {
 padding: 8px 0;
 grid-gap: 8px;
 grid-template-rows: repeat(10, 200px);
}

.review-wrap {
 flex-wrap: wrap;
 margin: 0;
}

.google, .move-left {
 position: relative;
 top: -50px;
}

.move-left {
 left: 0;
}

.review-wrap div img:not(.scale) {
  transform: scale(0.8);
 }

 .scale {
  transform: scale(1);
 }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 530px) {
 .gallery-grid {
  max-width: 80%;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(1, minmax(250px, 1fr));
  grid-template-rows: repeat(20, 300px);
 }

 .phrase-wrap div {
  display: none;
 }

 #quote-btn {
     font-size: 1.7rem;
     padding: 5px 17px 10px 17px;
 }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 450px) {
 #third-block h1 {
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin: 0 15px 0 15px;
 }

 .gallery-grid {
  max-width: 90%;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(20, 250px);
 }

 #quote-btn {
     font-size: 1.3rem;
     padding: 5px 13px 10px 13px;
 }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 375px) {
 .review-wrap div img:not(.scale) {
  transform: scale(0.7);
 }

 .scale {
  transform: scale(0.9);
 }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 350px) {
 #testimonials div{
  margin: 15px;
 }

 .gallery-grid {
  max-width: 90%;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(20, 200px);
 }
}
```

Comment: Most likely your browser cached the old CSS file. Open the website in an incognito window and it should show the new CSS. You can also use a [cache busting technique](https://css-tricks.com/strategies-for-cache-busting-css/) to force the browser to load the new CSS file.

Comment: So does that mean that all these issues I'm experiencing would only be seen on my computer??

Comment: Your computer and anyone else who has previously viewed the site and has not cleared their cache since you made the update.

Comment: Dang this is a real problem. For other users, will this update automatically? Or do they have to manually clear the cache?? Also before you made your first post and before I tested it out in incognito, I changed the name of the css file and that worked?

Comment: Changing the name of the file would work because it will no longer match the file that is cached in the browser. A more common solution is to just append a string onto the CSS filname such as `<link href="style.css?v=1.1">` and then each time you make a CSS change, just iterate the version number. There are more solutions in the link I provided in my first comment.